# .NET 4.5.2 not available in VS2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio

We are developing in VS2013 on Windows 7, and now that MS has announced withdrawal of support for .NET 4, 4.5 & 4.5.1 we have installed 4.5.2.  However in VS2013 we cannot set projects to use .NET 4.5.2. .NET 4.5.2 is just not listed as an option in the project properties.

All the usual things have been done, such as restarting Windows and so on. Is there a trick?

I am hoping we are not being 'forced' to upgrade to VS2015. For prudence' sake we have to stay behind the bleeding edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this version its the "Developer Pack" and you will have the option available.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637